# NodeJS and Passport: user is randomly changing

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I've added nodejs passport login to my app and everything worked fine, until I committed changes to production. The issue is pretty wired: user is randomly changes sometimes when I reload the page.

Here is my app.js code:

```
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');  
var passport = require('passport');
var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser()) 
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    maxAge: 60 * 5,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mysql.createConnection(dbConfig.connection).then(
    function (connection) {
        require('./config/passport')(passport, connection); // pass passport for configuration
    }
);
```

Here is what I have in configs/passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
module.exports = function (passport, connection) {
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.name);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (name, done) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? ", [name])
            .then(function (rows) {
                done(null, rows[0]);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Error getting user form DB: ", err);
                done(err);
            });
    });

passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
                usernameField: 'username',
                passwordField: 'password',
                passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
            },
            function (req, username, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", [username])
                    .then(function (rows) {
                        if (!rows.length) {
                            done(null, false); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
                        }

                        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                        else if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password)) {
                            done(null, false); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
                            // all is well, return successful user
                        }
                        else {
                            done(null, rows[0]);
                        }

                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log("Login Failed: ", err.body);
                        done(err);
                    });
            })
    );
};
```

And this is what I have in every route file:

```
router.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        user.init(req.user);
        next(); // pass control to the next handler
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Does anyone had similar issue? Seems like I've made some simple and stupid error, because google can't find similar issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be issue with objects storing by node js in memory. I don't fully understand how this is happened, but this is what I found.

I stored req.user in userModel object, and if there are a lot of requests on server, this userModel object sometimes gets messed up with data from different users.

The solution was to directly user req.user everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing two different queries:

```
// passport.deserializeUser()
connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = ? ", [name])

// In the Passport verification handler
connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", [username])
```

My guess would be that `name` isn't unique, and that you want to use `username` everywhere.

As an aside: you're setting `maxAge` to 300 *milliseconds*.